# I want to sort an array according to another array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

my friend wrote this code for me but unfortunately, I can't completely understand this code, I know what the methods push, filter and forEach do But I can't understand what happened in the function, so I'm looking for a brief explanation for the function. And thank you.

```
items = [ 
    ['Anne', '1'],
    ['Bob', '2'],
    ['Henry', '3'],
    ['Andrew', '4'],
    ['Jason', '5'],
    ['Thomas', '6']
]

sorting = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ];
result = []
sorting.forEach(function(key) {
    var found = false;
    items = items.filter(function(item) {
        if(!found && item[1] == key) {
            result.push(item);
            found = true;
            return false;
        } else 
            return true;
    })
})

result.forEach(function(item) {
    document.writeln(item[0])
})
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you don't understand. If you understand each of the functions, you should just be able to follow through on what they're all doing. Write down the results on a piece of paper.

Comment: This is the part where my mind starts to spin  if(!found && item[1] == key) {
            result.push(item);
            found = true;
            return false;
        }

Comment: That makes it only filter out the first match.

Comment: `found` is false until it finds the first match, then it becomes true.

Comment: Actually is very bad example to learn.. so confusing

Comment: This is a very confusing way to do it.

Comment: well if there is a way that is easier or less complicated than this code I would like to see it please

Answer (score 1):

The `filter()` call is filtering out the first element of the array whose number matches `key`. The `found` variable is used to stop filtering after finding a match, the rest of the array is returned unchanged.

And while it's filtering, it pushed that item onto the result list.

A more straightforward way to write it would be:

```js
sorting.forEach(function(key) {
  var index = items.findIndex(item => item[1] == key);
  if (index != -1) {
    result.push(items[index]);
    items.splice(index, 1);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filtering each element of the given data with a strange approach, you could tak a direct sorting by getting the indices of the items and take the delta as sorting value.

This approach takes [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with delta who define the relation between two items.

```js
var items = [['Andrew', '4'], ['Bob', '2'], ['Anne', '1'], ['Henry', '3'], ['Jason', '5'], ['Thomas', '6']],
    sorting = [ '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6' ];

items.sort((a, b) => sorting.indexOf(a[1]) - sorting.indexOf(b[1]));

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```